# SUM from group of every x rows

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I am making line graph from huge number of data from MySQL database. I can't pull out all of the data because allowed memory size in PHP would get exhausted so I need to re-sample the data.

I can't select (for example) every 3rd row from the database because each data point represents relative value (=change in user balance like +5 instead of actual state of user balance which could be 1000) so what I would need is SUM from group of n rows.

```
example of data in database
-10
-10
-10
 20
 20
-20
-10
-10
 20

expected output for SUM grouping by 3 rows
-30
 20
  0
```

Comment: You can get a very large result, as long as you fetch just a couple of records at a time, output the data that goes with it, and make sure you clean up (or re-use) the variables. If you follow those rules, then there's virtually no dataset too large to output through PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is with variables.

```
select sum(data)
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := -1) const
     ) t
group by rn div 3;
```

You should really have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows, so the subquery would have an `order by <ordering column>` to ensure consistent results.